# Calculating Distance Between Two Lat's and Longs Within A Data Frame

Tags: r, geosphere

I have a data set that includes the latitude and longitude for each individual property address. As well, I have created two new columns (icelat, icelog) that include the latitude and longitude for one specific building in the state of Utah.

The data looks like this:

```
                               RowID PropertyAddressLatitude PropertyAddressLongitude  icelat    icelog
1: 000D655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.65195                -109.4085 40.2351 -111.6384
2: 000F655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.50952                -109.4763 40.2351 -111.6384
3: 0012CB31-D004-E911-80C7-3863BB43E813                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384
4: 0013655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.54184                -109.5031 40.2351 -111.6384
5: 0014655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384
6: 0015655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384
```

I would like to create a new column, called 'distance' that is the distance, in miles, from each property's latitude and longitude to the specific building in Utah.

I have tried several different methods of using the Geosphere package but am unable to get it to run through all of the 'PropertyAddressLatitude' and 'PropertyAddressLongitude' observations and automatically do the math against  'icelat' and 'icelog.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default units will be in meters, so I'll convert in-place.

```r
meter2mile <- 0.000621371
dat[, distance := meter2mile * geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(
        cbind(PropertyAddressLongitude, PropertyAddressLatitude),
        cbind(icelog, icelat)) ]
dat
#                                   RowID PropertyAddressLatitude PropertyAddressLongitude  icelat    icelog distance
# 1: 000D655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.65195                -109.4085 40.2351 -111.6384 161.7148
# 2: 000F655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.50952                -109.4763 40.2351 -111.6384 166.0397
# 3: 0012CB31-D004-E911-80C7-3863BB43E813                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384       NA
# 4: 0013655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                38.54184                -109.5031 40.2351 -111.6384 163.4240
# 5: 0014655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384       NA
# 6: 0015655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F                      NA                       NA 40.2351 -111.6384       NA
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- as.data.table(structure(list(RowID = c("000D655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F", "000F655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F", "0012CB31-D004-E911-80C7-3863BB43E813", "0013655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F", "0014655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F", "0015655E-1AEA-E811-80C3-3863BB430E3F"), PropertyAddressLatitude = c(38.65195, 38.50952, NA, 38.54184, NA, NA), PropertyAddressLongitude = c(-109.4085, -109.4763, NA, -109.5031, NA, NA), icelat = c(40.2351, 40.2351, 40.2351, 40.2351, 40.2351, 40.2351), icelog = c(-111.6384, -111.6384, -111.6384, -111.6384, -111.6384, -111.6384)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

(I inferred `data.table` from your sample data, please advise if this was incorrect.)

Comment: Perfect! Now that I see how you did it, it makes sense too. This is why I love this website ... learn something new literally every time I post a question.

Comment: BTW, my choice of `distVincentyEllipsoid` is not strictly required. Depending on your balance of performance and accuracy, you might choose `distHaversine`, `distGeo`, or `distMeeus`, depending on your data, beliefs, and several things outside of my wheel-house.

Comment: I typically go with Ellipsoid anyways, as the developer of the Geosphere package has said it is often the most accurate calculation.

Comment: That's one reason I use it (and in my application, I'm looking for distances on the sub-meter scale). However, it can be significantly slower than `distHaversine`. If you're looking at hundreds of miles, then these points you provided are only different by less than 200 meters. The slower performance is only a problem when you do it millions of times (which I do).